# How can I identify numbers which are mixed up in a string in R?

Tags: r, replace, gsub, substitution

I have a scanned document and after OCR I have multiple problems with the resulting figures that turn out in the wrong format.

`x <- c("9 243,51 233 286,08 18 386.21")`
or
`x <- c("9.243,51 233 286,08 18 386.21")`

Desired result is:
`"9.244,51" "233.286,08" "18.386,21"`

Todos: decimal digits should be separated by commas (which is not always the case). Spaces within a number should be replaced by a dot (but with care since spaces also separate numbers).

I would be happy about any help!

Comment: Is the original `.` never in the OCR?

Comment: This isn't possible without some strong assumptions regarding the number of digits before and after the decimal comma and even then it would be dangerous. Is improving scan quality and the OCR step not an option?

Comment: You're right, Roland, but I only have the PDFs to extract data from - fortunately I have checksums so I can verify validity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` and `strsplit` assuming that the original `.` is never in the OCR and all number have a recognised digit either as `,` or `.`.

```
. <- gsub("\\.", ",", x)
. <- gsub("(,\\d+) +", "\\1:", .)
. <- gsub(" +", ".", .)
strsplit(., ":")[[1]]
#[1] "9.243,51"   "233.286,08" "18.386,21"
```

Or assuming two digits after comma:

```
. <- gsub("[.,](\\d{2}\\b)", ",\\1", x)
. <- gsub("(,\\d{2}) +", "\\1:", .)
. <- gsub(" +", ".", .)
strsplit(., ":")[[1]]
#[1] "9.243,51"   "233.286,08" "18.386,21"
```

Or:

```
. <- trimws(strsplit(x, "(?<=[.,](\\d{2}\\b))", perl=TRUE)[[1]])
. <- gsub("\\.(?=\\d{2}$)", ",", ., perl=TRUE)
gsub("(?<=\\d) +(?=\\d{3})", ".", ., perl=TRUE)
#[1] "9.243,51"   "233.286,08" "18.386,21"
```

Comment: Dear GKi - thank you very much- this works perfectly for the specific dataset.
As you thought this is not always the case. Nevertheless, the two decimal digits make it possible to set up a common rule: Numbers should be separated after the blank beside the two digits decimal digits which could look like ,[0-9][0-9] or .[0-9][0-9] . Any Idea for this improvement?

Comment: Maybe the update comes closet to what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This works fine in my example, but not when the numbers already have a dot to separate the thousands.

Comment: Third version: "9.243,51" turns unfortunately to "9,24" and "3,51" instead of keeping the format "9.243,51"

Comment: I added a `\\b` maybe this solves it. But maybe you edit your question and add examples which need to be solved.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts and patience.